# FCM notifications not receiving on iOS TestFlight app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging, testflight

My app should receive Firebase Cloud Messaging push notifications. When I tested the app on my device through Xcode building the app was able to receive the notifications and display them in the notification center. However, when I published the app onto TestFlight and install it from that, the app no longer receives any notifications.

I am sure that I've set the APS Environment to "production"

Here is my info.plist:

[image: info.plist]

Here is my AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    @AppStorage("notifyThreshold") var notifyThreshold: NotifyThreshold = .eg3 // (duplicate)
    func seperate(){ print(); print("  -------- incoming notification --------")}
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    
    // Called when a remote notification is received while the app is running or in the background
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        FCMManager.setNotifyMode(threshold: notifyThreshold)
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        
        // Print message ID and full message
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        if !userInfo.isEmpty {
            print("userInfo: \(userInfo) m1")
        }
        
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
}




extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    
    // Called when the app receives a registration token from Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
      let deviceToken:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        print("Device token: ", deviceToken) // This token can be used for testing notifications on FCM
    }
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    // Called when a notification is about to be presented to the user while the app is in the foreground
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
          
        // TODO: Use sound modification here
        
        // Print message ID and full message.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            seperate()
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        if !userInfo.isEmpty {
            print("userInfo: \(userInfo) m2")
            print("  ----------------- end -----------------"); print()
        }

        // Call the completion handler with options you want choosing type of notification
        completionHandler([.banner, .badge, .sound])
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    }

    // Called when a user interacts with a notification, such as tapping on it
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
      
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        // Print message ID and full message.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          print("Message ID from userNotificationCenter didReceive: \(messageID)")
        }
        print("userInfo: \(userInfo) m3")

        completionHandler()
  }
    
}

class FCMManager {
    static func setNotifyMode(threshold: NotifyThreshold) {
        ...
    }
}
```